# Script to search for values in the log

Tags: bash, grep, tail

I have an update program that either completes the update successfully or goes into error and needs to be restarted.

I am implementing the task itself on Ansible, but to control the process, a dynamic reading of the log using tail and grep is necessary, so I am implementing a script that will perform the task on its side and give the output success and failure.

This script does not work out the elif function, and shows the status only on success

```
#!/bin/bash

if tail -f -n3 /var/log/messages | grep -q "File update download fail"
then
  echo "Restart update"

elif tail -f -n3 /var/log/messages | grep -q "Update success"
then
  echo "Update success"

fi

exit 1
```

Comment: What do you mean with "shows the status only on success", when you also say "This script does not work out of the elif function", which is where the echo for success is. Did you have the conditions swapped in your actual testing?

Comment: That said, what I think you're looking for is something like `result=$(tail -f -n3 /var/log/messages | egrep "(File update download fail|Update success)"` and then an if-else statement depending on which of the patterns you actually found. Right now, your first `if` will keep going until the `grep` finds a matching line, which it may never find, or the `tail` command exits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tail -f` generally does not exit on its own, and `grep -q` will only exit if it reaches end-of-file or matches a pattern. Combining the two commands results in a statement that is unlikely to ever exit until it succeeds, meaning you will probably never reach your `elif` condition.

What you need is a loop that processes each line of output and allows every condition to be checked against each line.

```
#!/bin/bash
tail -f -n3 /var/log/messages | while read -r line ; do
  case "${line}" in
    *"File update download fail"*)  echo "Restart update" ; exit 1 ;;
    *"Update success"*) echo "Update success" ; exit 0 ;;
  esac
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '
    /File update download fail/{print "Restart update"; exit 1}
    /Update success/{print "Update success"; exit 0}
' <(tail -f -n3 /var/log/messages)
```